# Create linux daemon which uses Multiprocessing and Multiprocessing.Queues

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, daemon

I have a task to listen UDP datagrams, decode them(datagrams have binary information), decoded information put in dictionary, dump dictionary to json string and then send json string to remote server(ActiveMQ).

Both decoding and sending to remote could be time consuming. In order to make program more scalable we create two processes (Multiprocessing.Process):

- Listner(listen datagrams, analize, create json and put it in Multiprocessing.Queue)
- Sender(constantly tries to get a json string from the queue to array, if length of array becomes above threshold - send all collected strings to remote server)

Now I need to make from it a proper linux daemon (which could be *start, stop* and *restart* via *service* command).

The question: How to make a daemon from python multiprocessing program. I have found no guide about this. Does anybody know how to do this, or have working example.

---

The following text is my attemts to acheve this:
I found small example of python daemon: http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html
so I rewrited my code (sorry for big code):

```
import socket
import time
import os    
from select import select    
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

import stomp
import json

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("DaemonLog")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler = logging.FileHandler("/var/log/testdaemon/testdaemon.log")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
log = logger
#Config listner
domain = 'example.host.ru'
port = int(9930)

#Config remote queue access
queue_cfg = {
    'host': 'queue.test.ru',
    'port': 61113,
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'queue': '/topic/test.queue'
}

class UDPListener():
    def __init__(self, domain, port, queue_cfg):
        # If I initialize socket during init I see strange error:
        # on the line: data, addr = sock_inst.recvfrom(int(10000))
        # error: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
        # So I put initialization to runListner function
        #self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        #self.sock.bind((domain, port))
        self.domain = domain
        self.port = port
        self.remote_queue_cfg = queue_cfg
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.isWorking = Value('b', True)
        self.decoder = Decoder()
        self.reactor = ParallelQueueReactor(self.queue)

        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path = '/var/run/testdaemon/testdaemon.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5

    def __assignData(self, addr, data):
        receive_time = time.time()
        messages = self.decoder.decode(receive_time, addr, data)
        for msg in messages:
            self.reactor.addMessage(msg)

    def runListner(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind((domain, port))
        while self.isWorking.value:
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = select([self.sock], [], [])
            for sock_inst in inputready:
                if sock_inst == self.sock:
                    data, addr = sock_inst.recvfrom(int(10000))
                if data:
                    self.__assignData(addr[0], data)
        self.sock.close()

    def runQueueDispatcher(self):
        while self.isWorking.value:
            connected = False
            while not connected:
                try:
                    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(self.remote_queue_cfg['host'], self.remote_queue_cfg['port'])])
                    conn.start()
                    conn.connect(self.remote_queue_cfg['user'], self.remote_queue_cfg['password'], wait=True)
                    connected = True
                except socket.error:
                    log.error('Could not connect to activemq server.')
                    time.sleep(20)

                if connected == True:
                    while self.isWorking.value:
                        msg = None
                        if not self.queue.empty():
                            #Now error appear hear even when not self.queue.empty()
                            msg = self.queue.get()
                        else:
                            time.sleep(1)

                        if msg is not None:
                            try:
                                data = json.dumps(msg)
                                conn.send(body=data, destination=self.remote_queue_cfg['queue'])
                                count += 1
                            except:
                                log.error('Failed to send message to queue.')
                                time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.isWorking.value = False

    def run(self):
        log.error('StartProcesses')
        dispatcher_process = Process(target=self.runQueueDispatcher, name='Dispatcher')
        listner_process = Process(target=self.runListner, name='Listner')
        dispatcher_process.start()
        listner_process.start()
        dispatcher_process.join()
        listner_process.join()
        log.info('Finished')
#------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    from daemon import runner

    app = UDPListener(domain, port, queue_cfg)

    daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
    daemon_runner.daemon_context.files_preserve=[handler.stream]
    daemon_runner.do_action()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Now I see error on msg = self.queue.get()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in
_bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/root/ipelevan/dream/src/parallel_main.py", line 116, in runQueueDispatcher
    msg = self.queue.get()   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 91, in get
    res = self._recv() EOFError
```

I did not see this errors when run UDPListner.run() manually. But with daemon runner it looks like new instances of UDPListner is created underneath and in different processes we have different Queue(and different self.socket too, when it initialized in **init**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: It was a bad idea to keep links to shared objects(Queue, Value) as members of class for the purpose of using by processes. It was working somehow without demonization. But when the same code was run in DaemonContext the os.fork() happened and somehow messed up links to objects. I am not quite sure if Multiprocessing module was designed to work 100% correctly inside a method of an object.

Second: DaemonContext helps to detach process from shell, redirect streams and do several other things related to daemon processes but I have not found any good way to check if such a daemon is already running. So I just used

```
if os.path.isfile(pidfile_path):
        print 'pidfile %s exists. Already running?' % pidfile_path
        sys.exit(1)
```